# where to write maven commands in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have seen on internet to run command like

```
mvn . . . . . something
```

but I am confused where to write this.

if in command prompt   cmd.exe

I tried mvn.exe it says command not found

because maven is in STS

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with Eclipse. Do you have Maven properly installed on your system? Have you tried just `mvn`?

Comment: @Ates Goral from the title it seems like he wants to run it from within Eclipse

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hope you have m2eclipse installed.

> Right click on project directory in
>   Eclipse > Run As > Run
>   Configurations... >  Double click
>   Maven Build > fill in name, select
>   base directory of the project, provide
>   goal (e.g. clean install), provide
>   profile that you want to build  (leave
>   blank for default, else profile names
>   space separated) > check options if 
>   any like (offline for -o etc) > click
>   run

this will be available in your menu bar for future usage.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run mvn from the cmd.exe you must:

1) Download maven (https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)

2) Add it to your Path and configure JAVA_HOME (see:
    https://maven.apache.org/install.html)

3) Navigate to the root directory of your project (in cmd.exe)

4) Run mvn (and any of the options like clean or install etc)

5) Then you can run "mvn . . . . . something"